# Modal Bootstrap - php | Jquery | Hidden

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, modal

Boa noite, pessoal.
Alguém poderia tirar uma dúvida minha...
Eu tenho dados de aniversario do Usuário que vem do Banco de dados,
fiz um **if** para comparar **se a data atual é igual ao dia do aniversario do usuário logado** no sistema:

```
if($stringReplace == date('m-d')){
   echo $this->element('modalAniversario'); 
}
```

então se for igual ele chama um Modal(Bootstrap) para desejar feliz aniversario, 
só que ai que está o problema se a pessoa clica no botão "Fechar" do modal, ele fica aparecendo toda hora porque ele fica nesse if toda vez, minha dúvida é tem alguma possibilidade para não aparecer mais o modal assim que a pessoa clicar no Botão tipo um Hidden na classe do modal ao clicar no botão "Fechar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, utilize o cookie para armazenar o dado no navegador, https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Exemplo:

```
if($stringReplace == date('m-d') && !isset($_COOKIE['aniversario']){
    echo $this->element('modalAniversario'); 
    setcookie('aniversario', true);
}
```

Desta maneira vai aparecer somente uma vez.

Comment: Perfeito, amigo, é isso mesmo, deu certo muito Obrigado.